# Исчезновение курсора мыши при бездействии

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cursor, mouse-event

Подскажите как можно сделать исчезновение курсора мыши, если пользователь не двигает мышью более 3 секунд.

Если пользователь начинает двигать мышью, то показать курсор.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    controlsOpacity: 1,
    isFullscreen: false,


  },
  methods: {
    fullscreen() {
      conosole.log(this.isFullscreen);
      this.isFullscreen == false ? this.isFullscreen = true : this.isFullscreen = false;
    },
    onMouseMove() {
      this.showControls();
      if (this.mouseWait == undefined)
        clearTimeout(this.mouseWait);

      this.mouseWait = setTimeout(() => {
        this.middleControlsOpacity = 0;
        if (this.isFullscreen)
          this.hideControls();
      }, 5000);
    },
    showControls() {
      this.middleControlsOpacity = 1;
      this.controlsOpacity = 1;
      this.$parent.$refs.main.style.cursor = 'default';
    },
    hideControls() {
      this.middleControlsOpacity = 0;
      this.controlsOpacity = 0;
      if (this.isFullscreen) {
        if (this.$parent.$refs.main.mousemove) {
          console.log('move');
        }
        this.$parent.$refs.main.style.cursor = 'none';
      }
    },

  },
  mounted() {

    this.$refs.main.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onMouseMove);
    this.$refs.main.addEventListener('mouseenter', this.showControls);
    this.$refs.main.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.hideControls);

  }

})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="main" ref="main" :style="{opacity: controlsOpacity}">
    <button>click</button>
    <button @click="fullscreen()">click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `if (this.mouseWait == undefined)` тут, вероятно, не  `==`. а `!==`

Comment: @РустамГимранов Обновил код.

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n Абсолютно верно. Это были мои тщетные попытки найти решение =)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Появление дива при отсутствии движений мыши](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/387114/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d1%83%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%88%d0%b8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Успеть, пока вопрос не закрыли. Пример, все таки применительно к Vue, чтобы лишних слушателей `addEventListener` не добавляли. В снипет не вставлял, все равно не позволит перейти в полный экран.

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="main" ref="main" @mousemove="onMouseMove">
        <div class="controls">
            Элементы интерфейса в кадре
            <button @click="switchFullscreen">[ Полный экран ]</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="">Закадровые злементы интерфейса.</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        // Модель нашего таймера.
        mouseWait: null
    },
    computed: {
    },
    methods: {
        // Определить, что находимся в полном экране.
        isFullscreen() {
            return document.fullScreen ||
                document.webkitIsFullScreen ||
                document.mozFullScreen ||
                document.msFullscreenElement;
        },

        // Обработать движение мышью.
        onMouseMove() {
            console.log('Обрабатываем движение мышью.');

            const isFullscreen = this.isFullscreen();

            // Если полный экран.
            if (isFullscreen) {
                // Показываем элементы управления.
                this.showControls();
                // Запускаем таймер.
                this.runTiming();
            }
        },

        // Запустить таймер.
        runTiming() {
            console.log('Запускаем таймер.');

            // Всегда очищаем предыдущий таймер
            // при вызове метода.
            clearTimeout(this.mouseWait);

            // Запускаем новый отсчет.
            this.mouseWait = setTimeout(() => {
                this.hideControls();
            }, 3000);
        },

        // Переключить полноэкранный режим.
        switchFullscreen() {
            console.log('Переключаем полноэкранный режим.');

            if (this.isFullscreen()) {
                this.exitFullScreen();
            } else {
                this.requestFullscreen();
            }
        },

        // Попытатьтся перейти в полный экран.
        requestFullscreen() {
            const element = this.$refs.main;

            rfs = element.requestFullscreen ||
                element.webkitRequestFullScreen ||
                element.mozRequestFullScreen ||
                element.msRequestFullscreen;

            rfs.call(element);
        },

        // Выйти из полноэкранного режима.
        exitFullScreen() {
            console.log('Выходим из полноэкранного режима.');

            if (document.exitFullscreen)
                document.exitFullscreen();
            else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen)
                document.webkitExitFullscreen();
            else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen)
                document.mozCancelFullScreen();
            else if (document.msExitFullscreen)
                document.msExitFullscreen();
        },

        // Показать элементы управления
        showControls() {
            console.log('Показываем элементы управления.');
            this.$refs.main.style.cursor = 'default';
        },

        // Скрыть элементы управления.
        hideControls() {
            console.log('Скрываем элементы управления');
            this.$refs.main.style.cursor = 'none';
        },
    }
});
</script>

<style media="screen">
body {
    background: #20262E;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

.main:-moz-full-screen,
.main:-webkit-full-screen,
.main:-ms-full-screen {
    background: #08c;
    color: #fff;
}

.main:fullscreen {
    background: #08c;
    color: #fff;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
~function () {
  var t;

  window.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
    if (t) {
      document.documentElement.classList.remove('no-cursor')
      clearTimeout(t)
      t = 0
    }

    t = setTimeout(() => document.documentElement.classList.add('no-cursor'), 3000)
  });
}()
```

```css
.no-cursor, .no-cursor * {
  cursor: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Примерно вот так :

```js
let to = 3000, ts = 0;

addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
  ts = Date.now();
  area.style.cursor = "default";
});

setInterval(() => {
  if (Date.now() - ts > to)
    area.style.cursor = "none";
}, 99)
```

```css
body, #area{width:100vw;height:100vh;overflow:hidden;margin:0}
```

```html
<div id="area"></div>
```

Comment: Зачем интервал-то? И почему 99?

Comment: @Qwertiy ну можно много таймаутов, как у тебя в ответе, а если задержка большая то в 3 секунды плохо попадает т.к интервал стартует сразу

Comment: @Qwertiy мне почему то кажется что 100500 таймаутов не лучше одного интервала, сколько их в твоем ответе будет создано и уничтожено сразу же, но плюс мой - твой :)

Comment: Кстати, вместо `new Date` лучше `Date.now()` - оно не будет лишние объекты создавать. Что касается интервала - он же продолжает крутиться даже если пользователь ничего не делает.

Comment: @Qwertiy про первое-  полностью согласен, забыл про него совсем, а второе имхо меньшее из зол